# Does IOS Evernote SDK Public API support multiple account?

Tags: ios, evernote

Does IOS Evernote SDK Public API support multiple account?

Can I use multi Evernotesessions to save user info?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Evernote iOS SDK - How do I authenticate with a token?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31582099/evernote-ios-sdk-how-do-i-authenticate-with-a-token)

Answer (score 2):

You can expose the authentication token using a category:

```
@interface ENSession(MultiSession)

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *primaryAuthenticationToken;

@end
```

Once you saved the token for each account, you can use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31582414/588879) to authenticate using the saved token.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use multiple account. Just save the developer tokens in an array.