# Evernote iOS SDK - How do I authenticate with a token?

Tags: ios, oauth, evernote

I am using Evernote SDK for iOS and I am saving the authentication token when the user has authorized access.

Once the user installs my application on a different device, I want to use that token to reauthenticate automatically, but it looks like SDK doesn't support that. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had the same issue last week, and their SDK indeed doesn't support it out-of-the-box, but after some research I found a solution that works perfectly. This solution mimics a valid authentication flow.

**A little background:**

When the `ENSession` class initializes, it retrieves the credentials that are saved on the keychain (unless `[[ENSession sharedSession] unauthenticate]` was called earlier). The problem is that the keychain is empty when using a different device, so our goal is to add a valid `ENCredentials` instance to the `ENCredentialStore`.

**Solution:**

1. Add the following imports to your code: `ENCredentials.h` and `ENCredentialStore.h`. We will need them later.
2. Initialize the `ENSession` like you already do, using `setSharedSessionConsumerKey:(NSString *)key consumerSecret:(NSString *)secret optionalHost:(NSString *)host`.
3. In order to create a valid `ENCredentials` object, we need to provide the following objects:

   - `NSString *` host
   - `NSString *` edamUserId
   - `NSString *` noteStoreUrl
   - `NSString *` webApiUrlPrefix
   - `NSString *` authenticationToken
   - `NSDate *` expirationDate

   The `host` is always `www.evernote.com` (as defined in `ENSession` under `ENSessionBootstrapServerBaseURLStringUS`).

   `edamUserId` is the user id you received when you got the original token. Same for the `expirationDate`. If you are not sure how to get them then you should use `[[ENSession sharedSession].userStore getUserWithSuccess:^(EDAMUser *user)` once authenticated.

   So the only objects that are actually missing are `noteStoreUrl` and `webApiUrlPrefix`. Their format is always:

   - noteStoreUrl: `https://www.evernote.com/shard/edam_shard/notestore`
   - webApiUrlPrefix: `https://www.evernote.com/shard/edam_shard/`

   Luckily, your token already contains `edam_shared` (value of `S=`, see [this](https://dev.evernote.com/doc/articles/authentication.php)):

   > @"S=s161:U=5ce3f20:E=1561182201b:C=24eb9d000f8:P=285:A=app:V=2:H=e8ebf56eac26aaacdef2f3caed0bc309"

   If you extract `s161` and put it in the URLs above it will work (I am sure you know how to extract that, but let me know if you're having problems).

Now we are ready to authenticate using the token. First, expose the necessary functions from ENSession using a category:

```
@interface ENSession(Authentication)

- (void)startup;

- (void)addCredentials:(ENCredentials *)credentials;

@end
```

And authenticate using the token:

```
ENCredentials *credentials = [[ENCredentials alloc] initWithHost:ENSessionBootstrapServerBaseURLStringUS edamUserId:userId noteStoreUrl:noteStoreUrl webApiUrlPrefix:webApiUrlPrefix authenticationToken:token expirationDate:expirationDate];
[[ENSession sharedSession] addCredentials:credentials];
[[ENSession sharedSession] startup];
```

The last line is important in order to refresh the `ENSession` and retrieve the new stored credentials.

Now you are authenticated and ready to query the SDK. Good luck.

Comment: Hi Aviram, I can't find "expirationDate" for EDAMUser, how do you get it?

Comment: Got it from: [session primaryCredentials].expirationDate